# firebase custom email action handler web

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js

I am trying to verify the email on my website it does verify the email but always gives error and doesnt go through .then actions most of the time. and the error is always this = Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () and this on rightside of this error https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/setAccountInfo?key=AIzaSyDSRV31z_Ssn5EqfT3c31jXwTe0xZeYLh8

this is my code

```
handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode) {
      this.loadingVerify = true
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.pageFace = 'verify'
    let vm = this
    auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
      vm.feed = 'success'
      vm.loadingVerify = false
      vm.newReq = false
    }).catch(err => {
      vm.loadingVerify = false
    })
    }, 1000);
  },
```

Comment: it was giving the sam error before i use settimeout i tried it just to make sure my app initializes firebase first but no good for errors

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own question, you can just use the edit link and change it to say what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this happened with me too , while I was trying to reset password .
Now what worked was that reset password custom url did receive the request and handler that did the verification(verifyPasswordResetCode) would always go to catch phrase saying that the actioncode was incorrect(with same error as mentioned above on the console) . -> to resolve this -> Project(on firebase) -> authentication -> removed users and again adde them .
now again create a new request(new actioncode ) and try again .
worked for me.